# Linear algebra, column space and row space

Tags: linear-algebra

I am stuck on a proof question,
I know a n by n matrix A and $$A=A^2$$, and I want to show that$$A=A^T$$,
how do you show this? Thank you.

Comment: Do you have any concrete reason to believe it is true, or do you just want it to be true?

Comment: Yes, by the definition of the column space and row space, and I am given that $A=A^2$, so $A=A^T$ must be true, but I am thinking how to show this, and of course stuck...

Comment: HERE (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3059796/if-a-a2-is-then-at-a-a) you can find a counterexample of what you're trying to show:
$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&-1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$